# How to compile object files in their own folder using makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

Every time I run the following makefile it keeps relinking and I don't know why:

```
CC=gcc

CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -Werror

MLX=mlx/libmlx_Linux.a

LIBFT=libft/libft.a

I_LIBFT=-Ilibft -Llibft -lft

I_LIBMLX=-Imlx -Lmlx -lmlx

LIB=$(I_LIBFT) $(I_LIBMLX)

COMPATIBILITY=-lX11 -lXext -lm

FRAMEWORK=-framework OpenGL -framework AppKit

HDR=-Iinclude

LIBHDR=-Ilibft -Imlx

SRC_DIR=src/

SRCS:=$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)*.c)

OBJ_DIR=obj/

OBJS=$(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)%.c, $(OBJ_DIR)%.o, $(SRCS))

all: $(LIBFT) app

$(LIBFT):
    make -C libft
    @echo "done libft"

$(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir $@
 
$(OBJS): $(OBJ_DIR)%.o: $(SRC_DIR)%.c $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(HDR) $(LIBHDR) -c $< -o $@ 

app: $(OBJS)
    @echo "making app"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(HDR) $(LIBHDR) $(LIB) $(COMPATIBILITY) -o FdF

clean:
    rm -rf obj
    make -C libft $@

fclean: clean
    rm ./FdF
    make -C libft $@

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re so
```

My folder structure:

```
+include
--fdf.h
+libft
--ft_a.c
--ft_b.c
--...
--libft.a
--Makefile
+mlx
--mlx.a
--mlx_linux.a
--mlx.h
+src
--a.c
--b.c
--...
Makefile (the one in question)
```

I tried altering it to this but it also isn't working:

```
NAME=FdF

CC=gcc

CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -Werror

LIBFT=libft/libft.a

I_LIBFT=-Ilibft -Llibft -lft

MLX=mlx/libmlx_Linux.a

I_LIBMLX=-Imlx -Lmlx -lmlx

LIB=$(I_LIBFT) $(I_LIBMLX)

COMPATIBILITY=-lX11 -lXext -lm

FRAMEWORK=-framework OpenGL -framework AppKit

HDR=-Iinclude

LIBHDR=-Ilibft -Imlx

SRC_DIR=src/

OBJ_DIR=obj/

OBJ=$($(SRC_DIR)%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)%.o)

all: $(NAME)

$(LIBFT):
    make -C libft
    @echo "done libft"

$(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir $@
 
$(OBJ_DIR)%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(HDR) $(LIBHDR) -c $< -o $@ 

$(NAME): $(OBJ) $(LIBFT) $(OBJ_DIR)
    @echo "making app"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(HDR) $(LIBHDR) $(LIB) $(COMPATIBILITY) -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf obj
    make -C libft $@

fclean: clean
    rm ./FdF
    make -C libft $@

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re so
```

My difficulty lies in trying to compile the object files without the changes being "invisible" on another folder and having being able to call `$(OBJ_DIR)%.o: %.c` From `$(NAME)`

I'm relatively new to Makefiles so I have a hard time figuring out more complex rules.
Is there an easier way to compile the c files into object files and then link those files into an executable?

I think I might have complicated this one.

Comment: That's too muh vertical scrolling for me, I'm afraid, but here's a couple of hints: Your first one rebuilds because the target is `app`, but that target doesn't build a file named `app`. Also, anytime you find yourself putting `-I` (capital `I`)  and `-l` (lower-case `l`) in the same make variable, you can be pretty sure you're doing something wrong. The include directory needs to go *before* the `.c` files in the compile line. The library filename needs to go *after* the `.o` files in the link command (or after the `.c` and `.o` files in a combined compile-and-link).

Comment: You might want to use make's options '-d' and '-p' to learn how make works with your makefile. -- To tackle your issue, step back and write your makefile incrementally, reading its documentation and tutorial. Experiment with simpler layouts. You don't need to actually compile and link, a simple copy and concatenation is sufficient for such experiments. -- If you want an answer concerning your second makefile, please elaborate on "_it also isn't working_".